# Canvas.drawBitmap cutting source in half

Tags: java, android, animation, canvas, android-canvas

I've been trying to do some sprite animation in Android (it's a college exercise), but I'm having a strange problem. Instead of drawing the rectangle I defined as source, it draws exactly half of that rectangle.

Here's the code for my drawing method

```
public class Sprite {
Bitmap image;
Point frameSize;
int[] rows;
public int curFrame;
public int curRow;

public void draw(Canvas c, Paint p, Vector2 pos)
{
    Rect src;
    int left = curFrame * frameSize.x;
    int top = curRow * frameSize.y;
    int right = left + frameSize.x;
    int bottom = top + frameSize.y;

    src = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    Rect dest = new Rect((int)pos.x, 0, (int)pos.x + frameSize.x, frameSize.y);

    c.drawBitmap(image, src, dest, p);
}
```

Here's the image I'm using [image: Megaman SpriteSheet]

All frames are of equal size (44x40), and the image is 440x80, and I give this value as frameSize when I call the method.

Point is basically an object that holds a pair of x,y ints.

Vector2 is an object that holds a pair of x,y floats.

I also render some text for debug purposes.

Here are a few screenshots: [image: screenshot: frame zero] [image: screenshot: frame one] [image: screenshot: frame two]

I'm sorry, the screenshots are enormous. I don't know if there's a way to show them smaller in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can not see your code. What important is this:

```
int left = currIndex * peopleWidth;
int top = 40;
int right = left + peopleWidth;
int bottom = 80;
//clip the bitmap to show
Rect src = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
//set the display location in view
Rect display = new Rect(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, display, null);
```

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.rajesh.customcamera.R;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;

/**
 * Created by rajesh.zhu on 2017/9/28.
 */

public class MovingPeopleView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "MovingPeopleView";
    private int defaultWidth = 44;
    private int defaultHeight = 40;
    private int mWidth = 0;
    private int mHeight = 0;
    private int peopleWidth = 44;
    private int peopleHeight = 40;
    private int currIndex = 0;

    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public MovingPeopleView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MovingPeopleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MovingPeopleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //match_parent || absolute_value
            mWidth = widthSize;
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //wrap_content
            mWidth = Math.min(defaultWidth, widthSize);
        } else {
            mWidth = defaultWidth;
        }

        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            mHeight = heightSize;
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            mHeight = Math.min(defaultHeight, heightSize);
        } else {
            mHeight = defaultHeight;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.icon_moving_people);
        //Log.i(TAG, "Width:" + mBitmap.getWidth() + ", Height:" + mBitmap.getHeight());
        //you can set the peopleWidth and peopleHeight here
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        int left = currIndex * peopleWidth;
        int top = 40;
        int right = left + peopleWidth;
        int bottom = 80;
        //clip in bitmap to show
        Rect src = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
        //set the show location in view
        Rect display = new Rect(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, display, null);
    }

    public void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        run();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void run() {
        if (isRunning) {
            Observable
                    .timer(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
                            currIndex++;
                            if (currIndex == 10) {
                                currIndex = 0;
                            }
                            Log.i(TAG, "run");
                            invalidate();
                            run();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public void recycler() {
        if (mBitmap != null) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
            mBitmap = null;
        }
    }
}
```

you can use it in XML:

```
<com.rajesh.customcamera.view.MovingPeopleView
    android:id="@+id/moving_people"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Comment: That Observable part looks dangerous. You should put that code somewhere else and watch for subscription. Maybe start observable in onAttach a unsubscribe in onDetach or on visibility change.